# When did the practice of doing Kiddushin followed immediately by Nisuin begin?

Tags: marriage, kiddushin-eirusin, maseches-kesubos

**not really related to**: "[Why in olden days was there a long break between Kiddushin & Nisuin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99436/why-in-the-olden-days-was-there-such-a-long-break-between-kiddushin-nisuin)?"

---

In the times of the Talmud ([Ketubot 57a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.57a?lang=bi)) there was usually a significant amount of time between *kiddushin*/*erusin* (betrothal) and *nisuin* (marriage).

However ever since the Middle Ages ([source](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10434-marriage-ceremonies)) the practice has been to do the *kiddushin* and *nisuin* one after the other under the chuppah.

**When did this practice of doing Kiddushin followed immediately by Nisuin begin?**
Do we have any *teshuvos* or documentation from the Rishonim as to when exactly and why this practice began?

Comment: Well, if Rashi instituted the reading of the Kesubah under the Chupah as a Hefsek between Kiddushin and Nisuin, it must be at least from before Rashi's time.

Comment: Is there any reason to think this was a specific change at a specific point in time and not just something that was always possible becoming more common over time? You're asking for something precise when it might not exist.

Comment: Probably when people became poorer. Although, considering what many are spending on weddings, vorts, Lechaim's and showers now, that reasoning doesn't work.

Comment: @DoubleAA you're right- I assume that little by little it was whittled away until eventually done away with. The exact moment of change may not exist, but anything close/ acknowledging that it was not as common as once was would be also great

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56844/5120

Comment: @DanF, indeed, in Mishpat HaKetubah, that's one of the first reasons he brings, that Rashi was machrim that they should be done back to back to save money